# PL/SQL instruction to get numeric column precision

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, type-conversion

My goal is to create a function that converts a `NUMBER` variable to a `VARCHAR2` while replacing commas for dots as decimal separator. Besides, the string is returned with a mask which depends on the integer and decimal sizes of the number passed as `I_qty_value`.

```
declare

L_result  VARCHAR2(20);          

FUNCTION CONVERT_QTY_FORMAT(I_qty_value IN NUMBER,
                            I_precision IN NUMBER,
                            I_scale     IN NUMBER)

RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  --
  L_conv_value       VARCHAR2(255);
  L_mask             VARCHAR2(50);
  L_integer_size     NUMBER := I_precision - I_scale;
  L_decimal_size     NUMBER := I_scale;   
  --
BEGIN
  --
  -- Apply mask only if price is a decimal.
  --
  IF round(I_qty_value) = I_qty_value THEN
    --
    L_conv_value := TRIM(TO_CHAR(I_qty_value));
    --
  ELSE
    --
    -- Mask constructor based on value's length and precision.
    --
    L_mask := LTRIM(LPAD('0', L_integer_size , 9)) || 'D' || LTRIM(LPAD('0', L_decimal_size, 0));
    --
    -- Convert number to string using previous mask. 
    --
    L_conv_value := TRIM(REPLACE(TO_CHAR(I_qty_value, L_mask),',','.')); 
    --
  END IF;
  --
  RETURN L_conv_value;
  --
END CONVERT_QTY_FORMAT;  

begin

L_result := CONVERT_QTY_FORMAT(1000.999, 6, 2);
dbms_output.put_line(L_result);  

end;
```

Although the function is already working, the two input parameters (`I_precision` and `I_scale`) are being manually passed. **I would like to create an additional function which would return the variable number precision and scale** based on the input variable datatype. Is there any PL/SQL instruction or maybe a core table that may help me doing this?

For example, let's suppose `tbl1_1.column_1` is a `NUMBER(8,3)`.

What's the best way to get both 8 and 3 values from `column_1`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the optional third argument to `to_char()` to avoid the `replace()` step, and add `FM` to the mask to avoid the `trim()` step as that suppresses leading spaces.

Comment: Also if you're trying to figure out the original precision/scale of `I_qty_value` from *within* `CONVERT_QTY_FORMAT` then you can't. The best you can see is the data type of the formal argument, but you already know that. By the time your function sees that value it has been implicitly converted (if necessary) from whatever type the caller knows it as (whether it's a numeric literal, a column or a variable; and whether it was already a number, or a string, etc.) to your formal argument type - an unconstrained number in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this information in `user_tab_cols` and `all_tab_cols` views:

```
create table tbl1_1(column_1 number(8,3));

select column_name, data_precision, data_scale 
  from user_tab_cols 
  where table_name = 'TBL1_1' and column_name = 'COLUMN_1';
```

---

```
COLUMN_NAME                    DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
------------------------------ -------------- ----------
COLUMN_1                                    8          3
```

Comment: Thank you! Now imagine that I declare a variable as `L_xpto   NUMBER(8,3)` and I want to pass L_xpto as a parameter, without it pointing to any table type. In that case, I can't use the core table because the datatype is not a table type. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: For variables defined in procedures, functions - I doubt you can find this. You can view some definitions of arguments in `all_arguments`. For the rest - I don' know.